# moving multiple elements in an array javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array `["a","b","c","d","e"]`.

I want to move element index 1,2 to move one step up/down in the order so that new array would be `["b","c","d","e","a"]`.

If it is single element only, I can do that, but I could not figure out, how to do that in JavaScript.

The number of index elements to be  moved can be any, e.g. it can be 1 element only or more than 2.

Please help me.

Comment: "If it is single element only, I can do that" then why not doing it twice?

Comment: index is zero based.

Comment: @caramba, thanks, I fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

A little function if you want to move the indices by an arbitrary offset.

```js
//returns a new array with the items shifted
function move(arr, offset=0){
  //positive offsets move right
  const pivot = (offset < 0? 0: arr.length) - offset % arr.length;
  //positive offsets move left
  //const pivot = (offset < 0? arr.length: 0) + offset % arr.length;
  return arr.slice(pivot).concat(arr.slice(0, pivot));
}

let arr = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
for(let i=-5; i<10; ++i){
  console.log("shifted by %i %s", i, move(arr, i));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `push` and `splice` ()

```
var noOfItems = 2;
arr.push.apply( arr, arr.splice( 0, noOfItems ) );
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
var noOfItems = 2;
arr.push.apply( arr, arr.splice( 0, noOfItems ) );
console.log(arr);
```

Or if you want to do the reverse, then use `unshift`

```
arr.unshift( arr.pop()  )
```

And for multiple elements

```
arr.unshift.apply( arr, arr.splice(-2)  )
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
var noOfItems = 2;
arr.unshift.apply( arr, arr.splice( -noOfItems )  )
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: How can I move element down using this, please help?

Comment: @raju Did you checked the demo attached? It is moving the number of elements (which you specified) down.

Comment: What did you meant by **move element down**? Is it not the same thing you had given in your question?

Comment: This is working perfectly, what I am saying is how to get reverse output e.g. ["a","b", "c", "d", "e"] => ["e","a","b", "c", "d"]

Answer (score 0):

You could shift and push the element.

```js
const
    down = array => array.push(array.shift()),
    up = array => array.unshift(array.pop());

var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

up(array);
console.log(array);

down(array);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: How can I move element down using this, please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.prototype.unshift`, `array.prototype.push` and `array.prototype.splice`:

```js
var arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
function rotateRight(arr, nb) {
    var rightPart = arr.splice(arr.length - nb, arr.length);
    arr.unshift(...rightPart);
}

function rotateLeft(arr, nb) {
    var leftPart = arr.splice(0, nb);
    arr.push(...leftPart);        
}

rotateRight(arr, 3);
console.log(arr);
rotateLeft(arr, 3);
console.log(arr);
```